# Error message when installing requirements.txt for a cloned repository

Tags: git, github, pip, requirements.txt

I cloned a repository and am trying to install the requirements.txt like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/developmentseed/pillbox-engine.git
$ cd pillbox-engine
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/scisco/dj-database-url.git /private/var/folders/95/txp8yg_x07n2t_r6t4mgrycw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-x_7ghqug Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've looked into this and am unable to figure out the cause.

Comment: What is printed by `git clone git://github.com/scisco/dj-database-url.git /private/var/folders/95/txp8yg_x07n2t_r6t4mgrycw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-x_7ghqug`?

Comment: @ElpieKay I get `fatal: remote error. Repository not found`

Comment: `https://github.com/scisco/dj-database-url` could be a private repository which needs permission for access.